# Expose ng-form in scope and reference in ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms, angularjs-templates

I am attempting to do something like this:

```
<div ng-form="testForm" ng-init="$ctrl.doStuffWithForm(testForm)>
```

Where I define a form/publish the form to the current scope with the name `testForm` and pass that form object to `$ctrl.doStuffWithForm()` in the `ng-init`. However, what appears to be happening is that, at the time of the `ng-init`, the form creation and/or the creation of `testForm` in the scope has not happened yet (other testing indicates to me that `testForm` *does* point to a form controller at a *later* point in the Angular lifecycle).

Is there any way for me to pass the form controller to a method in the `ng-init` like this? Or should I be doing it another way? Is there an attribute similar to `ng-init`, but that is used later in the lifecycle? What I am trying to do is basically an `ng-repeat` on an element with an `ng-form`, and pass each form to a controller method when each element is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve my desired results by putting the `ng-init` in a child element of the `ng-form` element:

```
<div ng-form="testForm">
    <div ng-init="$ctrl.doStuffWithForm(testForm)></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `$ng-init` directive. Simply assign the `ng-form` to a property of  the `$ctrl` object:

```
<div ng-form="$ctrl.testForm">
    {{$ctrl.testForm.$dirty}}
</div>
```

Comment: This has worked in other scenarios for me, but in this case, I wanted to call a method on the form in the `ng-init`. Thanks for the suggestion though!